# JavasScript method to redirect most urls: (www., http://, https://)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there a JavaScript method that would redirect both of these:

```
url = 'www.google.com';
url = 'https://www.google.com';
```

As it seams `window.open(url)` requires to have the `http` in front of it or it would redirect to `mysite.com/wwwgoogle.com`

Or should I use another method to redirect?

The solution would be used for user inputted urls so I need to facilitate for as much input "styles" as possible.

Comment: Create a dummy anchor tag and set `target="_blank"` and `href` to concerned URL. Now trigger its click

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!url.startsWith('http://') && !url.startsWith('https://')) 
  url = window.location.protocol + '//' + url;
```

Thanks [Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh) for the comment

Comment: Instead of hardcoding `http://`, you should use `window.location.protocol + "//" + url`

Comment: You're absolutely right I kind of didn't pay much attention will fix it :) thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can even override `window.open()` function as below so any url which does not starts with `http` or `https` this function append http and redirect

please find below code

```
window.open = function (open) {
        return function (url, name, features) {
        url = addhttp(url);
        return open.call(window, url, name, features);
    };
}(window.open);

function addhttp(url) {
   if (!/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\//i.test(url)) {
      url = "http://" + url;
   }
   return url;
}

window.open("google.com");
window.open("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach would be to use `regex`

```
/^http(s?):\/\//
```

#### Sample:

```js
function hasProtocol(url) {
  var regex = /^http(s?):\/\//;
  return regex.test(url)
}

function appendProtocol(url) {
  console.log("parsing url: ", url)
  // Take your site's protocol instead of any default value
  return window.location.protocol + "//" + url;
}

function parseURL(url) {
  return hasProtocol(url) ? url: appendProtocol(url);
}

console.log(parseURL('www.google.com'))
console.log(parseURL('http://www.google.com'))
console.log(parseURL('https://www.google.com'))
```